# fieldState.error is empty and validation is not performed

Tags: material-ui, react-hook-form

For some reason, fieldState.error doesn't return anything even though I enter a value in the field that doesn't match the regex pattern.

When I set the properties:

{fieldState.error ? fieldState.error.message : ' '}
error={!!fieldState.error}

Although I fill out the form incorrectly - I still do not receive any message

What is the source of the bug?

```
"react-hook-form": "^7.45.2",
"@mui/material": "^5.14.0",
```

.

```
'use client'

import { useForm, Controller } from 'react-hook-form'
...

interface FormValues {
  category: string
  isbn: string
  ...
}

const ItemPost: React.FC<IItemPost> = ({
  openModal,
  handleClose,
}) => {
  const { data: session, status } = useSession()

  const regexTextPattern = /^[א-ת\s]+$/u
  const regexImageUrlPattern =
    /https?:\/\/[^\s\/$.?#].[^\s]*\.(?:jpg|jpeg|png|gif|bmp|svg|webp|ico|tiff?)/m
  const regexDanacodePattern = /^\w{12}$/
  const regexIsbnPattern = /^\d{10}(?:\d{3})?$/
  const regexBarcodePattern = /^\d{12,13}$/
  const regexMaxLoanPeriodPattern = /^(?:[3-9]|1[0-4])$/
  const regexAddressNumPattern = /^[0-9]+$/
  const regexZipCodePattern = /^[0-9]{7}$/

  const { watch, control, handleSubmit } = useForm<FormValues>({
    defaultValues: {
      category: '',
      isbn: '',
      ...
    },
  })

  const onSubmit = async (data: FormValues) => {
    try {
      console.log(data)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  }

  return (
    <SpringModal handleClose={handleClose} openModal={openModal} label={''}>
      {status === 'authenticated' ? (
        <Box
          component="form"
          sx={{
            '& .MuiTextField-root': { m: 1, maxWidth: '100%' },
          }}
          noValidate
          autoComplete="off"
          onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
        >
          <Controller
            control={control}
            name="category"
            rules={{
              required: 'Please select your category',
            }}
            render={({
              field: { onChange, onBlur, value, name, ref },
              fieldState,
            }) => (
              <TextField
                ...
              </TextField>
            )}
          />
          {watch('category') && (
                  <Controller
                    control={control}
                    name="barcode"
                    rules={{
                      required: 'Please enter a barcode number',
                      pattern: {
                        value: regexBarcodePattern,
                        message: 'Please enter a valid barcode number',
                      },
                    }}
                    render={({
                      field: { onChange, onBlur, value, name, ref },
                      fieldState,
                    }) => (
                      <FormControl
                        fullWidth
                        sx={{
                          m: 1,
                        }}
                        error={!!fieldState.error}
                      >
                        <InputLabel htmlFor="barcode">
                          Barcode number
                        </InputLabel>
                        <OutlinedInput
                          id={name}
                          inputRef={ref}
                          value={value}
                          inputProps={{
                            inputMode: 'numeric',
                          }}
                          endAdornment={
                            <InputAdornment position="end">
                              <Tooltip title="Will be implemented soon">
                                <span>
                                  <IconButton
                                    disabled
                                    aria-label="barcode reader button"
                                    onClick={handleClickBarcodeReader}
                                    edge="end"
                                  >
                                    <BiBarcodeReader />
                                  </IconButton>
                                </span>
                              </Tooltip>
                            </InputAdornment>
                          }
                          label="Barcode number"
                          onChange={onChange} // send value to hook form
                          onBlur={onBlur} // notify when input is touched/blur
                        />
                        <FormHelperText>
                          {fieldState.error ? fieldState.error.message : ' '}
                        </FormHelperText>
                      </FormControl>
                    )}
                  />
              )}
           
                  <Box
                    sx={{
                      paddingBlockStart: 3,
                    }}
                  >
                    <Grid container columnSpacing={2}>
                      <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
                        <Controller
                          control={control}
                          name={'item-name'}
                          rules={{
                            required: 'Please select a item-name',
                            pattern: {
                              value: regexTextPattern,
                              message: 'Please enter a valid item name',
                            },
                            // validate: (value) => testTextPattern(value),
                          }}
                          render={({
                            field: { onChange, onBlur, value, name, ref },
                            fieldState,
                          }) => {
                            console.log('Value:', value)

                            return (
                              <TextField
                                fullWidth
                                id={name}
                                inputRef={ref}
                                name={name}
                                value={value}
                                label={`${watch('category'!)
                                  .split(' ')
                                  .map(
                                    (word) =>
                                      word.charAt(0).toUpperCase() +
                                      word.slice(1)
                                  )
                                  .join(' ')} Name`}
                                helperText={
                                  fieldState.error
                                    ? fieldState.error.message
                                    : ' '
                                }
                                error={!!fieldState.error}
                                onChange={onChange} // send value to hook form
                                onBlur={onBlur} // notify when input is touched/blur
                              />
                            )
                          }}
                        />
                      </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                  </Box>
                </>
              ) : (
                <></>
              )}
            </>
          )}
          
                <Button>
                  Submit
                </Button>
            
      ) : (
          ...
      )}
    </SpringModal>
  )
}

export default ItemPost
```